# Frequency of Values by Date in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in Pandas that looks like this.  `date` is an index of dtype `datetime64`.

```
                                  keyword id
date
2017-03-31 21:22:33+00:00             cat  0
2017-07-07 11:28:36+00:00             dog  1
2017-03-31 01:18:50+00:00             cat  2
2017-03-31 21:03:39+00:00             cat  3
2017-08-23 13:26:43+00:00        elephant  4
```

I would like a result that counts the keywords by day like this:

```
2017-03-31 cat 3
2017-07-07 dog 1
2017-08-23 elephant 1
```

I am new to Pandas, so I am learning.  I have tried things like:

```
df.resample('D').keyword.value_counts()
```

which returns:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape ...
```

Apparently, I need to use `resample` because the date is an index.  I'm not really sure how to proceed. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `get_level_values` with `date`(Get the date part from the datetime format)

```
df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0).date,df.keyword]).size()
Out[867]: 
            keyword 
2017-03-31  cat         3
2017-07-07  dog         1
2017-08-23  elephant    1
dtype: int64
```